Missing include file in LLVM/clang: <stdfloat>
My code successfully builds with LLVM/clang when I link it against GNU/GCC Standard Library (libstdc++). However, when linked to LLVM's one (libc++), there is a missing header file: <stdfloat>.
From a search for the stdfloat token, I get:
/usr/include/c++/14/stdfloat
/usr/lib/llvm-19/share/libc++/v1/std/stdfloat.inc

The first belongs to GCC, the second to clang. The contents of stdfloat.inc looks similar to what it should be, but it is not an include file and is not found by CMake.
AFAIK, I installed all LLVM/clang related packages (binaries, libraries, ...).
Is it possible that that header is missing? Could it be an issue of my packaging system (Ubuntu)?

Ubuntu 24.10

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23, stdfloat is not implemented in libc++ yet.

Considering that the compiler also doesn't seem to support the extended floating point types, the missing header is a minor inconvenience.

The .inc file is a modules file. All those .inc files goes into the std module.

@TedLyngmo - Tried with import stdfloat;, and that module is not found. It looks like work in progress.

@Pietro It should be import std; but I don't think that's ready either.

@TedLyngmo - Yes, I just tried with std and I get the same error.

If anyone wants to reply to this question, I will accept it and close it. Thanks
